# There is a Rock-climbing proposal in Area 51

Tags: discussion

There is a [Rock Climbing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42410/rock-climbing) Proposal. Should we pick this up? Someone flagged it as a possible duplicate of sports, but we have a far larger Climbing list of questions than they do.

Answer (score 6):

Climbing questions are welcome and will be much better received here.

Comment: +1 I have a feeling a dedicated rock-climbing site won't have enough traffic/questions.

Comment: Agreed... un-necessary fragmentation IMHO

Answer (score 1):

I thought I heard somewhere that the sports proposal was more along the line of competitive sports - if so then this would be by far the better place for them.

Comment: Thanks for posting the discussion there, I didn't know how to go about it properly.